# Two pulse to create one pulse circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, flipflop, pulse

I have two pulse quick outputting of an Op Amp at a particular voltage. What I am trying to do is have an output pulse to trigger at the first rising edge pulse and fall at the second rising edge pulse. I also want my output to be the same voltage as my two input pulse. I have attached an image for clarity.

Thanks
[image: Two quick pulse within 0.1s at a desired voltage]

Comment: Looks to me like you want a buffered peak detector and a MOSFET controlled by a T flip-flop. Probably also a second FET to discharge the peak detector's capacitor after the second pulse.

Comment: Can you show a second scope view with a greatly decreased time axis to show the shape of the pulses?

Comment: If you can use a micro controller, it'd be pretty easy and more reliable to debounce since it looks like each of those pulses have multiple edges/noise spikes.

Answer (score 0):

Break the design down into blocks

- 0. pulse detect. Threshold
- 1. buffered Peak & Hold cct.
- 2. switch to follow 1) from 12V supply within 5% say
- 3. also set FF and arm it to enable reset with a 1-shot window if 2nd trigger is missed (n.t.h) so OR 2nd Pulse , timeout
- 4. return to zero V? Or 1V?
- 5. At what impedance  for each voltage and tolerance.?
- 6. Consider what meets all specs after all defined specs, consider fault conditions.
- 7. Define rise time min. And interval min/max,
- 8. consider “nice to have specs”, BUT specify all “must haves” for design  validation tests (DVT)
- Revise all my assumptions to meet yours and review again before choosing any parts

A solution can be trivial, but DVT depends greatly on your tolerances and specs for V, Z, t .